# Create Tridion Tag Cloud with Taxonomy Keywords?

Tags: tridion, tridion-2011, tridion-content-delivery

Content in the CMS is tagged with Keywords and after publishing they are used as Tracking Keys and the value is incremented each time a Page is loaded.  In the past a DB Query was used with the Tridion Broker DB to produce a tag cloud.  I would like to change this and use the Tridion Broker API instead.

The Tridion Online Documentation has a [nice example](http://sdllivecontent.sdl.com/LiveContent/web/pub.xql?action=home&pub=SDL_Tridion_2011_SPONE&lang=en-US#url=/LiveContent/web/search.xql?c=t&pub=SDL_Tridion_2011_SPONE&lang=en-US&action=search&query=tracking%2520keys&scope=&min=20&max=0&sort=&chunk=10&sid=lcSearch.runSearch1351682918563&currentQuery=tracking%2520keys&currentScope=&eventType=lcContent.loadDocconcept_897F8B16081F47579A37A9EB4FDB5B4F&query=&scope=&filename=TaxonomyKeywordCriteria.xml&docid=concept_897F8B16081F47579A37A9EB4FDB5B4F&inner_id=&tid=&addHistory=true&resource=)  (login to http://sdllivecontent.sdl.com/ first).  The example shows how to get the count of a keyword using the API.

I would like to have an aggregate query instead of getting the count 1 keyword at a time.  Is it possible with the Broker API or using Ambient Framework?

```
string strTaxURI = "tcm:34-70-512", strTaxKeywordURI = "tcm:34-549-1024";
Query myQuery = new Query();
Criteria myCriteria = null;

TaxonomyKeywordCriteria taxonomyKeywordCriteria = new TaxonomyKeywordCriteria(strTaxURI, strTaxKeywordURI, false);
myCriteria = taxonomyKeywordCriteria;
myQuery.Criteria = myCriteria;

// filter code limiting results commented out....

string[] itemURIs = myQuery.ExecuteQuery();
foreach (string itemURI in itemURIs)
{
      Response.Write(itemURI + ", ");
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't think you can achieve what you need by using the BrokerQuery API. You can, however, use the Taxonomy API to get a full taxonomy and to look at the ReferencedContentCount of each Keyword in that Taxonomy.

```
TaxonomyFactory taxonomyFactory = new TaxonomyFactory();
Tridion.ContentDelivery.Taxonomies.Keyword category = taxonomyFactory.GetTaxonomyKeywords("tcm:9-3-512");
Response.Write(category.ReferencedContentCount);

if (category.HasChildren)
{
     // get the category.KeywordChildren and loop over them
}
```

Hope this helps.

Cheers,
Daniel.